# Highstock - How can i display the open, high, low, close in the line or area charts tooltip

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm trying to display the open, high, low, close in the line or area chart's tooltip. Right now, the data for the line and the area charts is being sent in a JSON array which looks like this

```
{timestamp, close}
```

Now for OHLC or candlestick charts this JSON changes to

```
{timestamp,open, high, low, close}
```

I've tried this method which only works for OHLC and candlestick.

```
tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {



                        /*
                         * tooltip formatter function
                         * 
                         */
                        var d = new Date(this.x);
                        var s = '';

                        if (chartGlobalOptions.range.indexOf("m") >= 0) {

                            s += '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b><br />';

                        } else {

                            s += '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y [%H:%M]', this.x) + '</b><br />';

                        }


                        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                            if (point.series.name.indexOf("Volume") >= 0) {

                                /*
                                 * if the series is volume, then don't show the decimals
                                 * 
                                 */
                                s += '<b><span style = "color:' + point.series.color + ';">' + point.series.name + ' </span>' + ' : ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 0) + '</b><br />';
                            } else if (point.series.type == 'candlestick' || point.series.type == 'ohlc')  {

                                s += '<b><span style = "color:' + point.series.color + ';">' + point.series.name  + ' : ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.point.close, 3) + '</b><br />';
                                s += '<span style ="color:' + point.series.color + ';">Open</span>: ' + point.point.open +
                                     '<br/><span style ="color:' + point.series.color + ';">High</span>: ' + point.point.high +
                                     '<br/><span style ="color:' + point.series.color + ';">Low</span>: ' + point.point.low + 
                                     '<br/><span style ="color:' + point.series.color + ';">Close</span>: ' + point.point.close + '<br/>';
                            }

                            else {
                                s += '<b><span style = "color:' + point.series.color + ';">' + point.series.name + ' </span>' + ' : ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 3) + '</b><br />';
                            }



                        });
                        return s;
                    },
                    shared: true
                },
```

What modifications are needed to be done in order to display ohlc values in the tooltip of the line chart ? I've been trying to find a solution for quite some time without any success.

Thanks,

Maxx

**EDIT**

Here is the series option that i'm setting

```
series: [{
                        type: chartGlobalOptions.chartTypes.name,
                        name: $('#symbol-name').text(),
                        data: data.prices,
                        id: 'Price Axes',
                        dataGrouping: {
                            units: groupingUnits
                        }
                    }, {
                        type: 'column',
                        name: 'Volume',
                        data: data.volume,
                        yAxis: 1,
                        dataGrouping: {
                            units: groupingUnits,
                            approximation: 'close'
                        }
                    }]
```

And here is the data that i'm getting from the server.

```
{"prices":[{"x":1387377184000,"y":1.05,"high":1.06,"low":1.05,"open":1.06,"close":1.05},{"x":1387377509000,"y":1.04,"high":1.06,"low":1.04,"open":1.05,"close":1.04},{"x":1387378295000,"y":1.04,"high":1.04,"low":1.04,"open":1.04,"close":1.04},{"x":1387379370000,"y":1.04,"high":1.04,"low":1.04,"open":1.04,"close":1.04},{"x":1387380217000,"y":1.04,"high":1.04,"low":1.04,"open":1.04,"close":1.04},{"x":1387381181000,"y":1.04,"high":1.04,"low":1.04,"open":1.04,"close":1.04},{"x":1387381324000,"y":1.03,"high":1.03,"low":1.03,"open":1.03,"close":1.03},{"x":1387382146000,"y":1.03,"high":1.03,"low":1.03,"open":1.03,"close":1.03},{"x":1387383229000,"y":1.03,"high":1.03,"low":1.03,"open":1.03,"close":1.03}],
"volume":[[1387377184000,0],[1387377509000,35600],[1387378295000,0],[1387379370000,25300],[1387380217000,0],[1387381181000,0],[1387381324000,4500],[1387382146000,1700],[1387383229000,4000],[1387383788000,2600],[1387384004000,1000],[1387384218000,2900],[1387385045000,0],[1387385840000,10000],[1387386013000,100],[1387386627000,6200],[1387386981000,0],[1387387439000,2500],[1387387728000,2500],[1387387950000,0],[1387388920000,0],[1387389210000,500],[1387389890000,15500],[1387390124000,400],[1387390988000,11900],[1387391264000,4900],[1387391832000,0],[1387392803000,0],[1387393369000,6200],[1387393774000,200],[1387394744000,0],[1387395716000,0],[1387395904000,2800],[1387396334000,15000],[1387396689000,0],[1387397664000,0],[1387398328000,12300],[1387398706000,7000],[1387400379000,13000],[1387463638000,0],[1387464573000,46200],[1387465371000,4000],[1387465588000,0],[1387465948000,33000],[1387466607000,0],[1387466883000,11400],[1387468648000,13500],[1387470272000,12800],[1387470693000,0],[1387471718000,0],[1387472674000,0],[1387472742000,0],[1387473768000,100],[1387474795000,0],[1387475319000,29500],[1387475698000,99100],[1387475822000,14400],[1387476297000,3400]]}
```

Here is how i'm setting the data in the server

```
$this->price[]          = array (
                                              $eachRow[ "timestamp" ] * 1000 ,
                                              $eachRow[ "close" ] * 1 ,
                                              $eachRow[ "high" ] * 1 ,
                                              $eachRow[ "low" ] * 1 ,
                                              $eachRow[ "open" ] * 1 ,
                                              $eachRow[ "close" ] * 1
                            ) ;

return json_encode ( array (
                                     "prices"             => $this->resultArray[ "prices" ] ,
                                     "volume"             => $this->resultArray[ "volume" ] ));
```

And i do a  `var data = JSON.parse(data);` at the very beginning just after i get the values from the server. Please let me know what is wrong with my program. I mean if i hardcode the same values directly in the data object i get the correct result.

Comment: Does anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add that info to your points, for example:

```
    series: [{
        //type : 'ohlc',
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: [{
            x: 1367884800000,
            y: 100,
            high: 150,
            low: 90,
            close: 120,
            open: 100
        }, {
            x: 1367984800000,
            y: 120,
            high: 170,
            low: 120,
            close: 160,
            open: 120
        }, {
            x: 1368084800000,
            y: 160,
            high: 160,
            low: 90,
            close: 120,
            open: 160
        }]
    }]
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UTsT4/

Note: when you will have a lot of points, and dataGrouping will be used, point info (opten/high/low/close) will be lost. So that will only work with disabled dataGrouping.

Comment: Perfect.. This is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot for this and for the jsfiddle. Yes i'm aware of the data being lost. But what if i add a higher turbothreshold value like 1million would that preserve most of the points.

Comment: You can set to 0, to disable turboThreshold. Anyway turboThreshold have nothing in common with dataGrouping. dataGrouping groups a couple of points into one, according to approximation used. And groups (for a line) only y-value. Not custom info like high/low/close/myCustomProperty.

Comment: Ok got it. And thanks again for this, it really helped.

Comment: Sorry to bother again but i'm still getting an undefined error even after i followed your post. Surpisingly the tooltip works when i hardcode the values in the data object. Please check the edit of my question.

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please. Like I did demo for you.

Comment: In fiddle you are parsing JSON, after removed that, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8Kq6T/4/

Comment: Oh yes i see. My bad. Alright its all good now. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.